# MX records set up

Tags: domain, g-suite, mx-record, gmail

I just want to know how other people set up their MX-entries for mail accounts used with google apps. 
I work at a local web-hosting firm and we get a lot of tickets from clients who want to set up these settings.
I just set them up something like:

```
example.com.    14400   IN  MX  10 ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
example.com.    14400   IN  MX  10 ASPMX4.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
example.com.    14400   IN  MX  15 ASPMX5.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
example.com.    14400   IN  MX  15 ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
example.com.    14400   IN  MX  30 ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
```

I see another firm (rival one) who sets up way more MX-records ? Roughly, around 10-15 entries.
Am I doing something wrong ? More is better in this case ? Is there a secret that I'm not on too ?

Comment: That's a pretty standard setup for Google Apps for Your Domain.

Comment: Those look like an older MX record set. I'd switch to the new set in Google's documentation. Yours will *likely* continue to work fine.

Comment: The configuration listed in the Question is incorrect (per Google) and should not be used. Also, it'd be a really good idea if your account control panel (or whatever you call it) had a button for "Configure for Google Apps/Mail".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should set up the MX records per Google's documentation.

http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=174125

```
1 ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
5 ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
5 ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
10 ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM
10 ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM
```

Note that the 1/5/10 priorities can be 10/15/30 or 1/2/3 or 1/100/1000 and it'll be fine - they just have to be in ascending order like that.

10-15 MX records for Google Apps is not something I've seen and is likely incorrect or at least unnecessary.

Comment: +1 This is the *One and Only Google Ordained™* configuration. Anything else is a violation of their ToS technically, though they probably don't care as long as the money keeps rolling in.